# Content search web part to return article pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, content-search-web-part

My scenario: I have added a content search web part to a page and trying to return pages from the link "https://tenantname.sharepoint/sites/sitename/pages/foldername".

I have just created the "foldername" folder and reindex the site so that it shows up in the content query result box but unfortunately i see nothing.

Any clue why this simple task is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online it takes at least 15 minutes, sometimes longer , before the content is indexed.
However I would suggest that you verify the search using the Sharepoint search query tool in order to ensure where the issue is

Comment: i have check with the tool but still i don't know why it can't see that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Security & Compliance Center to export the crawl log, check if the pages in the new folder are crawled.

Check the article about [How to download or view SharePoint Online Search Crawl Logs using Security & Compliance Center](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/svarukala/2017/08/09/how-to-download-or-view-sharepoint-online-search-crawl-logs-using-security-compliance-center/)